# Calculating Averages in an Array and Displaying them on Page Load, Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an array called `products`that is structured like:

```
    {
            "_id": "150",
            "name": "Milk",
            "description": "Skimmed",
            "price": "10",
            "ratings": [
                      { 
                        "email": "xyz@mail.com",
                        "rating": "5"
                      },
                      { 
                       "email": "abc@mail.com",
                       "rating": "3"
                      },
                      { 
                       "email": "def@mail.com",
                       "rating": "1"
                      },
                      ]
},
   {
            "_id": "151",
            ...
            ...
            ...
```

I want to calculate the average rating of a product and display it on page load, using Vue.js.

My HTML page for products has a `v-for = "(product, key) in products"` Which I use to display all the products by name,desc etc.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          "_id": "150",
          "name": "Milk",
          "description": "Skimmed",
          "price": "10",
          "ratings": [
              {
                "email": "xyz@mail.com",
                "rating": "5"
              },
              {
                "email": "abc@mail.com",
                "rating": "3"
              },
              {
                "email": "def@mail.com",
                "rating": "1"
              },
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    // mapping each item of products to merge averageRating calculated
    this.products = this.products.map(product => {
      // ratings summation
      const totalRatings = product.ratings.reduce((acc, { rating }) => acc += Number(rating), 0)
      const averageRating = totalRatings/product.ratings.length
      // returning the merge of the current product with averageRating
      return {...product, averageRating}
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for = "(product, key) in products" :key="key">
      name: {{ product.name }} ~ averageRating: {{ product.averageRating }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
products = [
   // The above array data ..
];

this.modifiedProducts = products.map(product => {
      const average = product.ratings.reduce((total, next) => total + parseInt(next.rating), 0) / product.ratings.length;
      return {
        ...product,
        averageRating: average.toFixed(2)
      }
});
```

.html

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="product in modifiedProducts">
    name: {{ product.name }} ~ AverageRating: {{ product.averageRating }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a simple javascript code where you can use a for loop to do that as well...

```
   <script>
    let ratingSum = 0
    let myArray ={
            _id: "150",
            name: "Milk",
            description: "Skimmed",
            price: "10",
            ratings: [
                      { 
                        email: "xyz@mail.com",
                        rating: "5"
                      },
                      { 
                       email: "abc@mail.com",
                       rating: "3"
                      },
                      { 
                       email: "def@mail.com",
                       rating: "1"
                      },
                      ]
}
// stringify your array as json array
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(myArray)
// get the array length
var myArraylength = myArray.ratings.length
// use a for loop to loop through the array and sum all the ratings
for(i=0; i< myArray.ratings.length; i++){
    ratingSum += parseInt(myArray.ratings[i].rating)
}
// after getting the sum of the rating divide it on the array length
myAverage = ratingSum / myArray.ratings.length
console.log(myAverage)

    </script>
```